# How can I use an externally declared function as a jQuery .filter()?

Tags: jquery, filter

I'd like to use jQuery's `.filter()` with a function declared externally, rather than having the entire filter code in-line.

My particular example:

```
$('ul')
    .filter( function() { return aClassStartsWith(this, 'class_name_beginning') } )
    .each( function() { ... 
});
```

And I have this function declared after:

```
function aClassStartsWith (that, classPrefix) { 
    var reString = '\b' + classPrefix;
    var re = new RegExp(reString, "g");
    return that.className.match(re); 
}
```

Problem is, this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. Perhaps something to do with the `this` context?

Just to clarify the point of this filter, in case it matters: It's to find elements whose individual class names begin with a certain string. The `^=` operator can only operate on the `class="..."` attribute as a whole. For example, it will not find `apple` for `class^="ap"` on an element with `class="orange apple"`

I'd be grateful for any tips on getting this to work. Thanks!

Comment: you need to return from filter

Comment: @baao means you literally need the word `return`

Comment: More specifically, change `aClassStartsWith(this, 'class_name_beginning')` to `return aClassStartsWith(this, 'class_name_beginning')`

Comment: I just tried this (adding the word `return` before calling the function), but to no avail. The selector still returns zero elements. Placing the filter code in-line works properly: `$('ul').filter( function() { return this.className.match(/\bclass_name_beginning/g) }).length;` returns `1`

Comment: As it turns out, the reason this still wasn't working was because I failed to "escape the escape character" in the RegExp declaration -- `\\b` was required, instead of `\b`. This wasn't required when I spelled out the filter in-line as I was using a string literal there (`/ ... /`). The `return` was indeed missing too, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The filter method has the signature(index, element), when you are using the *this* keyword, you are targeting the Window, not the element inside the selector. Just wrap your method like this:

```
$('ul').filter( function(index, element) { return aClassStartsWith(element, 'class_name_beginning'));
```

The fiddle using a simple alert for the element className: https://jsfiddle.net/1bmrw9be/2/

And another, changing the background of element, chaining css method:
https://jsfiddle.net/2azsnsbo/

Comment: I'm not clear on what you changed, other than declaring the function using `var funcName = function () {}`, which I thought was interchangeable with my syntax: `function funcName () {}`. I do see your fiddle works but it doesn't actually demonstrate a working filter, only a successfully passed variable. I did try changing the first line of the function declaration as you suggested and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, the edit is coming!